# Angular - catch ng-click in directive and cancel it

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've written a directive that catches whether 'shift' is held down when a button is clicked, and calls a different function if so. The thing is, the original ng-click action is also being performed. I though preventDefault or stopPropagation would stop this but it appears not to be the case.

**HTML**

```
  <body ng-app="app">
      <div ng-controller="ctrl">
          <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="click1($event)" shift-ng-click="click2($event)">Click</button>
      </div>
  </body>
```

**JS**

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.click1 = function(event) {
        console.log("Click 1");
    }

    $scope.click2 = function(event) {
        console.log("Click 2");
    }
});

app.directive('shiftNgClick', function() {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        link: function(scope, el, attrs) {
            el.bind('click', function(event) {
                if (event.shiftKey) {

                    event.preventDefault();
                    event.stopPropagation();
                    scope.$apply(attrs.shiftNgClick);
                }
            })
        }
    };
});
```

So when the function called by scope.$apply() is called, so is the original ng-click() one. Resulting in click1() and click2() being called.

Is there a way to stop this happening, or would it be best to leave out ng-click totally, and put it all into a directive?

Plucker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/OL7Iwm?p=preview)

Thanks, Dan

Comment: Why not just use only  "click1" and have 2 different cases: if shift was held or not held?

Comment: Because I'd like to keep event stuff out of the controller, or do you mean in the directive? If so, that's what I'll be trying next.

Comment: In the directive - use only that and not both click and your shift-click

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`event.stopPropagation()` will only prevent parent handlers from catching the event. You're looking for `event.stopImmediatePropagation()`, which also prevents other handlers attached to the same element from running.